# Google Earth Engine cannot add null EE object as layer in risk map

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm working on a project in which I make a landslide risk map in Google Earth Engine -- I have each of the layers that I want to combine to show landslide risk, and I'm using this [overall vulnerability code](https://mygeoblog.com/2022/10/14/calculate-overall-vulnerability/) to help me. However, when I try to combine all factors into one index by adding

```
var total = ndvi.multiply(0.333).add(
   sla.multiply(0.333)).add(
   lc.multiply(0.333)).add(
 
Map.addLayer(total,{min:20,max:80,palette:"darkgreen,green,yellow,orange,red,darkred"},'landsliderisk'))
```

I get an error saying "cannot add null EE object as a layer".

Is this an issue with the code used to combine the indexes, or is there an issue somewhere else with my layers, and how can I fix it?